ChartJS and Vue-ChartJS: Scales in chart options do not work
I just started using ChartJS and VueChartJS and begin with a simple bar chart. The problem is that the scales in chartOptions do not affect the UI.I used ChartJS 4.4.2 and VueChartJS 5.3.1.
Here's my code:
<template>
    <Bar :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" />
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
    name: 'BarChart',
    components: { Bar },
    data() {
        return {
            chartData: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Data One',
                        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
                        data: [40, 20, 12]
                    }
                ]
            },
            chartOptions: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    x: {
                        barPercentage: 0.5,
                        categoryPercentage: 0.8,
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Custom Chart Title'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'top',
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: true,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>


Try use async/await with mounted function like async mounted() { await this.fetchData(); }. See chart-with-api-data

@user25009716 It does not work. I only use initial data in datasets.

Only barThickness works.

did you install ChartDataLabels and registered ?

@user25009716 I did not. I comment it but nothing changes.

@user25009716 I think it maybe because of scrollbar, so I switch to a simple example of VueChartJS (I have updated above). Everything works fine, except the scales. I changed scales many times but nothing changes.

barPercentage and categoryPercentage are not scale options so they won't work there.  If you add them to datasets property, they will.

For valid scale options see common scale options and additional bar chart scale options
